# I want to press several images in php and send the values to a form

Tags: php, image, forms

I have several images in a form php.I want to  retrive the values I have  i each foto.I have tried so,but I cant.Thanks for all

```
<form action="datos.php" action="sensores.php" method="POST">
       <tr>
       <td>Nombre:</td>
       <td> <img src="fotoPequeña.jpg" input type="hidden" name="nombre" value="PRUEBA HIDDEN"/>
        </td>
        </tr>
       </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `enctype = "multipart/form-data"` in form

Comment: <form action="datos.php" method="POST"  enctype = "multipart/form-data">
       <tr>
       <td>Nombre:</td>
       <td><img src="fotoPequeña.jpg"/><input type="hidden"  name="nombre" value="PROVE HIDDEN"/>
        </td>
        </tr> NO FUNCTION ,THANKS